# Laravel passport application how to handle internal requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a laravel application that I have recently installed laravel passport with. This application makes a series of internal api calls to retrieve data. With laravel passport whenever I make these internal api calls it gives back an unauthenticated error message.

I have added the 'auth:api' middleware to my api routes and want to be able to access them internally. Do I need to send a bearer token with the request to allow the request through. Also how would I generate this token?

Here is an example of the code with call to make internal api calls.

```
public function postToApi($url, $data) {
    $req = Request::create($url, 'POST', $data);
    try {
        $res = app()->handle($req);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the routes look

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Forum\Http\Controllers'], function(){
Route::get('reply/{id}', 'ReplyApiController@show' );
Route::get('thread/{id}', 'ThreadApiController@show' );});
```

Comment: There's this whole bit about consuming your own api with passport in the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is adding this to `.htaccess` of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

this second solution into your `Kernel.php` middleware groups.

```
\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
```

the third solution

```
/**
/* Indicates if cookies should be serialized.
/*
/* @var bool
 */
protected static $serialize = true;
```

in `Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php` fixed it for me.